# Updating DateTime field from a string yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff results in error

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to update a datetime field from a string of type yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff but without success:

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET MyDateTimeField = CAST('2021-02-20 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
 WHERE MyCondition
```

Below is the error I get:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value

Comment: This conversion works fine in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f811f68b7208abc871d1976346935ae4)

Comment: Seems the problem is caused by a different string.

Comment: Or the server's international settings are interpreting the day as 2 and the month as 20.

Comment: You would get the same result with `MyDateTimeField='2021-02-20' as there would be a default conversion.

Comment: Do you have a table trigger by any chance?

Comment: Maybe try    = CONVERT(varchar,  '2021-02-20', 103)

Comment: Finally I have solved by doing CONVERT(datetime, '2021-02-20 00:00:00.000', 121)

Answer (score 1):

Don't write the datetime values that way. They're not safe for all settings. Do this instead:

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET MyDateTimeField = '20210220'
 WHERE MyCondition';
```

That works for all regional settings and all date-related data types. I'm also presuming you don't want a time component. If you do, use this format:

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET MyDateTimeField = '20210220 23:10:15'
 WHERE MyCondition;
```

The only other option that's safe is the full ISO8601T format (but has to include the T part).